# Adding I/O Hooks for a Large Directory

Tags: linux, io, hook, fuse

I'd like to run a couple of simple hooks on certain I/O operations done in my home directory (`unlink` and `rename` in particular).
I've learned that with FUSE, I can move my `/home/user` to, for example, `/home/user_data` and have that mounted on an empty `/home/user` with a  FUSE program that adds the hooks I want.

Is it possible to do that somehow in place and in a way that will allow to tack this onto a setup where `/home/user` is already a mountpoint from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

How large that directory is? I'd give a try to  [inotifywait(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait):

```
$ inotifywait -m -r ~ -e delete -e move
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.

# ... mv test test.txt will trigger:

/home/user/ MOVED_FROM,ISDIR test
/home/user/ MOVED_TO,ISDIR test.txt
```